# Fund transfer from foreign account to Indian account

Tags: india, banking, international-transfer

Some person is willing to help Indian students for their studies by contributing 10 Euro every month , so I gave them my savings account.

Now I got email from the person saying he is not able to send money, they are asking me 21digit bank account number and swift code.

But my savings account has only 14 digit, how to help them? Do I need to change my savings account?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is not a scam.

It is expensive to transfer 10 EUR by SWIFT. It will cost 30 EUR in Banks fees.

If this is genuine ask them to use remittance service or western union

or you open a PayPal account and ask them to transfer money.